# How could I solve errors 'Package R doesn't exist' and 'Execution failed for task":app.compileDebugJavaWithJavac" ' errors in android studio?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, android-manifest

I have been trying to create android app taking an inspiration from Instagram clone that runs on Firebase. However, after just 3 videos I am getting these two errors in build up. The errors are:

1)

```
Package R doesn't exist.
```

2)

```
Execution failed for task "app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac".
```

My main code I guess is:

```
package com.rozgari.rozgari.profileuser;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class UserProfileActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_profile);
    }
}
```

Please help. The video series is 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PlgSC4YeBjY&list=PLK6pXSzzP1uYoyOKzTVSk3xgXq6wHQCnI&index=3

and video after which I got this error is number 3rd.

Comment: For your error 2 add the code of gradle file.

Answer (score 2):

In order to resolve error no. 1 Import the following file:-

```
package com.rozgari.rozgari.profileuser;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.rozgari.rozgari.R;

public class UserProfileActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_profile);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where...which file?